# Join not working in Oracle error is nctb : phone_number invalid identifier

Tags: oracle

I have 2 queries and want to retrieve data using join.

1st query is as below and retrieve column  "Phone_Number"

```
SELECT p.VALUE "Phone_Number"
FROM netcracker_rdb.RDB_BPI rd
JOIN netcracker_rdb.RDB_PROD_OFFER rpo ON rd.PRODUCT_OFFERING = rpo.OBJECT_ID
JOIN netcracker_rdb.nc_params_pim p ON p.object_id = rd.object_id
                                    AND attr_id = 9138903692913092143
```

2nd query is as below and retrieve 2 columns "MSISDN" and "shi"

```
SELECT TRIM (REPLACE (shid.msisdn, CHR (10), '')) "MSISDN", sc.imsi
FROM 
    (SELECT shl.iccid, MAX (shl.sim_history_id) AS shi
     FROM ninas_dba.sim_history_tb shl
     GROUP BY shl.iccid) shs, 
    ninas_dba.sim_history_tb shid, 
    ninas_dba.sim_history_tb sh,
    ninas_dba.sim_card_tb sc,
    ninas_dba.sim_card_type_tb sct,
    ninas_dba.Tenant_tb smt
WHERE     
    shid.iccid = shs.iccid
    AND sh.sim_history_id = shs.shi
    AND shid.sim_status_id = 102
    AND sc.iccid = shid.iccid
```

I want to join these 2 queries using 1st query's "Phone_Number" and 2nd query's "MSISDN" column

Comment: not able to retrieve phone_number column

Comment: Your question looks quite chaotic, would you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50922089/edit) it according to the rules? See: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Hi marc_s , actually we have been given this from another team and instructed to do not modified 2 queries and join them only accordingly. So i had to follow it. I will remember this point and use in future .. Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of double quotes. Nothing good in them.

Should be

```
SELECT "Phone_Number"                     --> double quotes here as well, if you used them ...
  FROM ( (SELECT p.VALUE "Phone_Number"   --> ... here
```

Or, as I suggested, no double quotes:

```
select phone_number
  from ((select p.value phone_number
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps best to include the phone_number as a sub-query and include in the where statement?

so something like this....

```
  SELECT 
            TRIM (REPLACE (shid.msisdn, CHR (10), '')) Phone_Number 

        FROM 
            (  
                SELECT 
                    shl.iccid, 
                    MAX (shl.sim_history_id) AS shi
                FROM 
                    ninas_dba.sim_history_tb shl
                GROUP BY shl.iccid
            ) shs,
        ninas_dba.sim_history_tb shid,
        ninas_dba.sim_history_tb sh,
        ninas_dba.sim_card_tb sc,
        ninas_dba.sim_card_type_tb sct,
        ninas_dba.Tenant_tb smt

        WHERE     
            shid.iccid = shs.iccid
            AND sh.sim_history_id = shs.shi
            AND shid.sim_status_id = 102
            AND sc.iccid = shid.iccid
            AND TRIM (REPLACE (shid.msisdn, CHR (10), '')) in (
               SELECT 
                  p.VALUE
               FROM netcracker_rdb.RDB_BPI rd
               JOIN netcracker_rdb.RDB_PROD_OFFER rpo
                 ON rd.PRODUCT_OFFERING = rpo.OBJECT_ID
               JOIN netcracker_rdb.nc_params_pim p
                 ON  p.object_id = rd.object_id
                     AND attr_id = 9138903692913092143
            )
```

As mentioned in other answers the quote is only necessary when there is a space in your alias so "Phone Number" would require quotes.

I also believe you need to re-evaluate what you are trying to achieve, there is a lot happening in this query to retrieve a single attribute. Perhaps there are different avenues to pursue to achieve the same result?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Thnx.. i will check this too, once i free from the work... its good to know second way too..